# 403 Error with Microsoft's ActiveSync Connection Test

Tags: exchange

I'm having trouble with ActiveSync. I'm in the process of setting up Exchange 2013 on a computer at home. I get a 403 error (screenshot at bottom) when running the Microsoft Connectivity Test for ActiveSync. I used AutoDiscover lookup with "ignore SSL" ticked. What can I do to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the built-in admin account doesn't have inheritance. I solved it by making a test account "acivesynctest".